# Obtain error details from Remote Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am adding [Remote Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/inc/remote-authentication?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to an ASP.Net Core Web API app as part of a migration process.

For normal exceptions, I get the developer error page with call stack, etc. whenever an unhandled exception was thrown.

But for exceptions with Remote Authentication `AddAuthenticationClient()` a 500 status code is returned with no other information

e.g.

```
builder.Services.AddSystemWebAdapters()
    .AddRemoteAppClient( options =>
    {
        var url = builder.Configuration[ "ProxyTo" ];
        options.RemoteAppUrl = new( url );
        var key = builder.Configuration[ "RemoteAppApiKey" ];
        options.ApiKey = key;
    } );
    .AddAuthenticationClient( true );
```

It doesn't seem to be an issue with the normal `UseDeveloperExceptionPage` setup, since I can get call stack details for all other errors until this `AddAuthenticationClient` method is called and the `[Authorize]` attribute is added to a controller/method.

Is there some other hook for finding the details of what's going wrong with remote authentication?

Comment: Your API may be simply passing on the 500 it receives from the remote app. So can you change the remote app's config or look for the exception details in it's logs or the Event Viewer on the machine where it runs?

Comment: Check out the WWW-Authenticate response header. Although you should have another problem also - it should be 401 in case the authentication went wrong.